# Overwriting table width declared in css, with the html width attribute

Tags: html, css, html-table, width

An unusual question that I haven't been able to locate the answer to:

Is it possible to overwrite tables styled with css, using the `width` attribute.

I would like html tables to default to a `width` of `100%` (using css), unless a numeric `width` argument is passed to my table in the markup.

Right now, if I set the `width` of my table to `auto` in css, I am able to overwrite the width using the `width` attribute, by applying it to the `table` element in the markup. However, `auto` does not default to a width of `100%`. If I set the `width` of my table to `100%` in css, then I am unable to overwrite the width using the `width` attribute, by applying it to the `table` element in the markup.

Does anyone know of a work-around so that I may have my table-cake and eat it too?

```css
.table-a {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 48px auto 16px;
}

.table-b {
  width: auto%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 48px auto 16px;
}
```

```html
<table class="table-a" width="200">
  <tr>
    <td>Foo</td>
    <td>Bar</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table class="table-b" width="200">
  <tr>
    <td>Foo</td>
    <td>Bar</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table class="table-b">
  <tr>
    <td>Foo</td>
    <td>Bar</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<p>Table A seems to show that the width attribute will not override external stylesheets the same way inline stylesheets.</p>

<p>Is there a way to ensure that when a width attribute is not passed to a table, that it defaults to 100%, and otherwise adheres to the width declaration/</p>
```

Comment: Can you post your code snippet for the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 48px auto 16px;
}

table:not([width]) {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table width="200">
  <tr>
    <td>Foo</td>
    <td>Bar</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Foo</td>
    <td>Bar</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<p>The :not() selector successfully enables me to use the width attribute in the markup and style every other table with a width of 100%.</p>
```

You can use `:not` selector. For example `table:not([width])`
Then css will be applied to all tables that haven't got `width` attribute

Comment: This is interesting. Perhaps the first use-case I've considered using `:not`. I will test.